# Overriding Spartacus interceptors not possible anymore?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Since upgrading `@spartacus/core` I've noticed that interceptors (among a few other injectables) have been aliased with prefixes of the Theta `ɵ` character.

I've noticed the Angular team typically does the same for internals that are not intended for override or extension. I presume that's what the spartacus team is going for too?

May I ask why these interceptors are regarded as internals?

We're currently integrating with our own separate OIDC server and in order to properly achieve this we've needed to override a few of the auth interceptors, namely `UserTokenInterceptor` and `ClientTokenInterceptor`.

Is there an alternative recommended approach or would we have to downgrade `@spartacus/core`?

We could make sure to check the Theta character alias token we're overriding each time we bump `@spartacus/core` too though this is kind of against the grain - I noticed the aliases change when we bumped spartacus to 2.x.

I've toyed with the idea of creating an overarching null interceptor to nullify other spartacus interceptors effects, though that's probably not possible for interceptors like the `ClientTokenInterceptor` that make their own network requests preflight.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, we'll discuss in the team and come back to you. Most likely this is done as part of our refactoring of session management. We've planned to do a lot of work on this before releasing 2.0, and quite likely this is why we already start dropping those interceptors from public api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently started to work on authorization module to support different OAuth flows and to make integration with external identity providers easier. With that changes we already thought about interceptors and there will be a couple of changes in them and they will be exported in the public `@spartacus/core` API. At the moment we target 3.0 release with the changes, but I can't promise any specific date.

Comment: Thanks for the response and that sounds great - looking forward to 3.0.